# Trying to get my delete button to sit on the right side

Tags: css

I'm not to good at css but i'm trying to get my button to sit next to the "posted by". I king of got the button in the are that i want it at but i want it to be inside of the box.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please share your attempted code.

Comment: please put some code example, so we know your html css structure

Comment: Without knowing the markup and styles for the modal, it's not possible for anyone to help you.

Comment: check the answer, i made base on your screenshot, if this is what you want, dont forget to tick and vote, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you dont know what you really need. Here I make an example from your screenshot, by using `flex` to align the content and the button, hope this might help you.

```css
.thebottom{
  background-color:#F5F5F5;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  padding:20px;
}

.theleft{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.deletebtn{
  background-color:#F24701;
  padding:10px 25px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="thebottom">
<div class="theleft">
  <div>
    Post by : ABC
  </div>
  <div>
  30th of August, 3AM
  </div>
</div>
<div class="deletebtn">DELETE</div>
</div>
```